# Generic data service with different return type

Tags: angular

I have created this generic data service that looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { Resource } from '../models/resource';

const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;

@Injectable()
export class DataService<T extends Resource> {

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private endpoint: string) {}

  public create(item: T): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient
      .post<T>(`${API_URL}/${this.endpoint}`, item);
  }

  public update(item: T): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient
      .put<T>(`${API_URL}/${this.endpoint}/${item.id}`, item);
  }

  read(id: number): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get(`${API_URL}/${this.endpoint}/${id}`)
      .map(response => response as T);
  }

  list(): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get(`${API_URL}/${this.endpoint}`)
      .map(response => response as T[]);
  }

  delete(id: number) {
    return this.httpClient
      .delete(`${API_URL}/${this.endpoint}/${id}`);
  }
}
```

Then I created a **CategoryService** that extends this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Category } from '../models/category';

@Injectable()
export class CategoryService extends DataService<Category> {

  constructor(httpClient: HttpClient) {
    super(
      httpClient,
      'categories'
    );
  }

}
```

So now I have all the CRUD methods available to that service. And I have since created a number of other services, each extend the `DataService`.
The issue is, I have come across an API endpoint that doesn't match the return type.
For example,
The endpoint "/categories", my data service expects all endpoints to return a  entity, for categories, that is a **Category**:

```
import { Resource } from "./resource";

export class Category extends Resource {
    name: string
}
```

But, there is an endpoint for the categories API that returns a list of **Questions**. The path for that is "/categories/2/questions".
How can I get that to work with my generic data service?
I assume the answer is I can't, but there must be a way around this, perhaps to supply the model type at each invocation rather than on instantiation?

Any help would be appreciated.
I hope it makes sense.

Comment: You could add a second parameter for each dataService function , that will be empty by default, but it will be appended to the URL so you can still alter the URL-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this new route is not generic. I would think that the `CategoryService` should be the class that implements the new method.

```js
export class CategoryService extends DataService<Category> {

  constructor(httpClient: HttpClient) {
    super(
      httpClient,
      'categories'
    );
  }

  getQuestions(id: number): Observable<Question[]> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<Question[]>(`${API_URL}/${this.endpoint}/${id}/questions`);
  }
}
```

You can get a reference to `endpoint` and `httpClient` by changing their access modifiers to `protected`

Answer (score 0):

I decided to remove the generic service, and use generic methods instead.
So the data service became (note the new `query` method:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private endpoint: string) {}

  create<T>(item: T): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient
      .post<T>(`${API_URL}/${this.endpoint}`, item);
  }

  update<T>(item: T): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient
      .put<T>(`${API_URL}/${this.endpoint}/${item.id}`, item);
  }

  read<T>(id: number): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get(`${API_URL}/${this.endpoint}/${id}`)
      .map(response => response as T);
  }

  list<T>(): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get(`${API_URL}/${this.endpoint}`)
      .map(response => response as T[]);
  }

  query<T>(path: string): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get(`${API_URL}/${this.endpoint}/${path}`)
      .map(response => response as T[]);
  }

  delete(id: number) {
    return this.httpClient
      .delete(`${API_URL}/${this.endpoint}/${id}`);
  }
}
```

And my category service became this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Injectable()
export class CategoryService extends DataService {

  constructor(httpClient: HttpClient) {
    super(
      httpClient,
      'categories'
    );
  }

}
```

To get my "category questions", I could just do this:

```
this.categoryService.query<Question>(`${this.category}/questions`);
```